OS exception while running the application core
I have an application core that includes an OS stack, which checks the interrupt source and ISR routines. While starting the application core, I am encountering an exception. I am using the AUTOSAR stack and receiving the "Stopped at vector catch" error. I am using the ARM M4 core, and it seems like I have encountered an exception. I have tried to understand the stack frame. Please find the Lauterbach debugger stack trace below.
-000    Os_Hal_UnhandledEXC(asm)
        
->      exception
-001    Os_CoreAsrGetAsrStatus(inline)
        
        ...
        OS_FUNC_ATTRIBUTE_DEFINITION(OS_LOCAL_INLINE P2VAR(Os_CoreAsrStatusType volatile, AUTOMATIC, OS_VAR_NOINIT), OS_CODE,
        OS_ALWAYS_INLINE, Os_CoreAsrGetAsrStatus,
        (
        P2CONST(Os_CoreAsrConfigType, AUTOMATIC, OS_CONST) Core
        ))
        {
376     return ((P2VAR(Os_CoreAsrStatusType volatile, AUTOMATIC, OS_VAR_NOINIT))Core->Core.Status);                           
-001    Os_CoreOsIsStarted(inline)
        Core = 0xEED1
        
350     return (Os_StdReturnType)(Os_CoreAsrGetAsrStatus(Core)->OsState == OS_COREOSSTATE_STARTED);                           
-001    Os_CoreShutdown(Error = 13, Synchronize = 1)
        Error = 13
        Synchronize = 1
        core = 0xEED1
        
1111    if(OS_LIKELY(Os_CoreOsIsStarted(core) != 0u))                                                                         
-002    Os_SystemShutdown(Error = ???)
        Error = ???
        
        currentCoreId = OS_CORE_ID_0 = OS_CORE_ID_MASTER
        
        ...
            if(core->Status->ActivationState == OS_CORESTATE_ACTIVATED_ASR)
            {
                (void)Os_XSigSend_ShutdownAllCores(Os_Core2AsrCore(core), currentThread, Error);
            }
            }
        }
        
        /* #30 Shutdown local core with shutdown synchronization. */
1263        Os_CoreShutdown(Error, TRUE);
-003        Os_ErrProtectionError(Fatalerror = ?)
        Fatalerror = ?
        status = ???
        
        ...
            /* #40 Handle protection hook return value. */
            Os_ErrHandleProtectionReaction(protectionReaction, status);
        
            /* #50 Resume interrupts. */
            Os_IntResume(&interruptState);
        
        }
        else
        {
1451            Os_SystemShutdown(status);
-004        Os_StackOverflowCheck(inline)
        
            Os_ErrProtectionError(OS_STATUS_STACKFAULT);
        Os_ThreadSuspendAndStart(inline)
        Current = 0x0
        Next = 0x0D
        CallPreThreadHook = 0
        
1065        Os_StackOverflowCheck();
-004        Os_IsrRun(Isr = 0x0D)
        Isr = 0x0D
        interruptedThread = 0x0
        interruptState = (Global = 1, Level = 0)
        
423         Os_ThreadSuspendAndStart(interruptedThread, &Isr->Thread, FALSE);
-005        Os_Isr_Core0_Exception_15(asm)
        
        ...
        OS_HAL_ASM_EXPORT(Os_Isr_Core0_Interrupt_161)
        OS_HAL_ASM_EXPORT(Os_Isr_Core0_Interrupt_321)
        
        
        /* Definitions of the ISR wrappers on OsCore0 */
        OS_HAL_ASM_IMPORT(OsCfg_Isr_CounterIsr_SystemTimer)
        OS_HAL_ASM_THUMB_FUNCTION
        OS_HAL_ASM_FUNCTION_BEGIN(Os_Isr_Core0_Exception_15)
62      Os_Hal_Cat2Entry_Interrupt OsCfg_Isr_CounterIsr_SystemTimer
-006        ST:0x81000000(asm)
    
    end of frame

However, I am unsure where exactly the issue is coming from. I would like to know how to debug this type of exception. Is the issue related to "Exception_15," or could it be due to a stack overflow? Any helpful suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Why do you think it has anything to do with the stack to begin with? Instruction trace is much more useful than stack trace. If you have instruction trace you'll immediately see how you ended up there.
